# Receiving duplicates with formula

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates, match, lookup

I have been trying to figure out this formula for the past 2 weeks! Now, the formula I am using works for the first few cells, then I start receiving duplicates and I cannot figure out why. I would also like the #N/A values to be blank, since I do need the formula down all of column C.

What is my goal?

I have over 1,000 competitor names and each competitor will be placed into an 'Event' (picture 1). These 'Event' names are placed in cell B5 of each worksheet (shown in pictures 2 and 3), up to 40 total events (worksheets).

So, in the first picture, Todd (D14) is in Event A (E14). I need Todd's name to show up in C9 of the 2nd picture, which with my formula it has; but, if you look down the following cells of the 2nd picture and into the 3rd picture, the names start duplicating. Then, when there are no further competitor names for events A and B, I receive #N/A values; which I would like to remain blank.​

The screen shots are just quick examples, but the competitors will also have their last names listed (format will be: first name _ last name).

Below is the formula I have for C9 (2nd picture)

```
=INDEX('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!D14:E$1201,MATCH('First Event'!$B$5,'COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!E14:E$1201,0),1)
```

Below is the formula I have for C10 (2nd picture)

```
=INDEX('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!D15:E$1201,MATCH('First Event'!$B$5,'COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!E15:E$1201,0),1)
```

Thank you for your time and help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this the way you are trying - typically `INDEX/MATCH` only will only retrieve **one** value - I assume you are deliberately not fixing the start of the range so that it shrinks by one each row....but that will only work when your previous match is always in the first row, which won't always be the case.

To get all the names associated with an event try this "array formula" in `First Event` worksheet cell `A9`

`=IFERROR(INDEX('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!D$14:D$1201,SMALL(IF('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!E$14:E$1201=$B$5,ROW('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!E$14:E$1201)-ROW('COMPETITOR NAMES ~ DIVISIONS '!E$14)+1),ROWS(A$9:A9))),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column

That will also stop you getting errors when names run out.

Note: it might be better to use this formula first on the competitor numbers (just change the first range in the formula to the relevant column) because if those are unique you can get the competitor names with a simple `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`